# CListCtrl with CImageList access HBITMAP for modification

Tags: c++, mfc, imagelist, clistctrl, hbitmap

I have a CListCtrl containing a CImageList so I can show HBITMAPs in my list (just plain color rectangle). I want to be able to replace a color. For exemple, if I select some color in the list, then hit replace, the color shall be changed. I use the following code:

```
   int nItem = 0;
   list<CustomColor>::iterator listCopyIter = pListCopy->begin();
   while( nItem<pListCtrl->GetItemCount() && listCopyIter!=pListCopy->end() )
   {
      if (pListCtrl->GetItemState(nItem, LVIS_SELECTED) == LVIS_SELECTED)
      {
         HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateBitmap(); //Just some function I use

         //IMAGEINFO* pItmData = (IMAGEINFO*)pListCtrl->GetItemData(nItem);
         //pItmData->hbmImage = hBitmap;
         //pListCtrl->SetItemData(nItem, (DWORD_PTR)pItmData);
         pImageList->Replace(nItem, CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap), RGB(0,0,0));
         *listCopyIter = color;
         return;
      }
      else
      {
         nItem++;
         listCopyIter++;
      }
   }
```

Where pListCopy is my std::list< CustomColor >* , pListCtrl my CListCtrl* and pImageList my ImageList*.

The problem is, sometimes, my CListCtrl doesn't use the same position as the ImageList (for exemple, item in CListCtrl pos 3 could use an image in ImageList pos 6). In that case, the HBITMAP replaced is wrong. That is why I tried the code in comments: tried getting the ItemData, casting it to IMAGEINFO, changing the value of the HBITMAP and then setting it back. But this gives me a writing access violation...

What am I overlooking? Is there a way to directly change the HBITMAP? I know I could always get every HBITMAP value from the ImageList and reposition them so they are in sync with CListCtrl, but that would not be very efficient and quite ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was I was using GetItemData wrong. GetItemData returns a DWORD_PTR (32 bits value). And I never used a SetItemData before. Now, when creating an item, I use this:

```
int nItemPos = pListCtrl->InsertItem(pos, string, imgpos);
pListCtrl->SetItemData(nItemPos, imgpos);
```

And then in my other function, I just cast the GetItemData to int in order to retrieve the image position, like this:

```
int pItmPos = (int)pListCtrl->GetItemData(nItem);
pImageList->Replace(pItmPos, CBitmap::FromHandle(hBitmap), RGB(0,0,0));
pListCtrl->RedrawItems(nItem, nItem);
```